# jQuery Tooltip and Mouseover Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I'm working on an MIT map of projects for an architectural firm, and trying to figure out how to keep the red dots mouseover state on while the mouse moves over the associated tooltips that pop up. Right now the mouseover turns off when the mouse moves to the tooltips.

Also, when either the dot or the link in the tooltip are clicked, I need the tooltip to clear and turn off. I noticed on an iPad that after clicking a tooltip link to a project page and then going back to the map page with the back button, the last tooltip for some reason stays stuck open. Doesn't seam to be an issue on desktops, but on mobile devices I need it to be cleared when they hit the back button.

Here is the site i'm referring to: http://www.digitour360.com/mit/ and the stylesheet is here: http://www.digitour360.com/mit/css/stylesheet.css

Below is the css code of the circle sprite for each button - i'm trying to somehow tie these to each of the tooltips. For example, if the mouse moves over red circle button 11 and then onto the tooltip for button 11, I do not want the red circle hover state to turn off until it leaves the tooltip.

```
#button { background:transparent url(../images/red-circle.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -2px; display:block; height:23px; width:23px; } #button:hover { background-position:0 -25px; opacity: 1; }'
```

And One more thing, what is the best way to make sure the tooltip is closed when any link is clicked inside of it? For some reason on mobile devices, when you finger hits to open the hover state and then you click a link on it, if you hit the back button, the tooltip stays stuck open.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Just edit the question, it's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: it is saying: new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. So can't post the code in the first post. Just look for the comment <!-- Button 11 --> for the start of one of the buttons, and look at the jquery script at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the events onShow and onHide on each of your tooltips and do modifications to the trigger object. I'll show this to you with your code.
Here are your trigger button divs:

```
<div id="eleven_div" class="button-eleven" style="display: block; ">
    <a href="projects/gantt/" id="button">Button 11</a>
</div>
<div id="ten_div" class="button-ten" style="display: block; ">
    <a href="projects/table/" id="button">Button 10</a>
</div>
...
```

And the corresponding javascript:

```
$(".button-one").tooltip({
    position: "center right",
    delay:300,
    effect: 'slide',
    direction:'right',
    offset: [30, -12],
    slideOffset: 30,
    slideFade:'true',
    slideInSpeed:350,
    slideOutSpeed:250
});

$(".button-two").tooltip({ 
    position: "bottom left",
    delay:300,
    effect: 'slide',
    direction:'left',
    offset: [-34, 20],
    slideOffset: 30,
    slideFade:'true',
    slideInSpeed:350,
    slideOutSpeed:250
});
...
```

First you have the attribute id="button" inside each of your a-tags inside the divs. It is absolutly wrong. Ids must not occur twice. So better change this into classes:

```
<div id="eleven_div" class="button-eleven" style="display: block; ">
    <a href="projects/gantt/" class="button">Button 11</a>
</div>
<div id="ten_div" class="button-ten" style="display: block; ">
    <a href="projects/table/" class="button">Button 10</a>
</div>
```

Now place the callback function for the red dots to be shown. The function is called every time a tooltip is shown or will be hide again. And it adds or removes a class to the a-tag inside the triggering div. New code:

```
function hovering()
{
    this.getTrigger().find("a").first().toggleClass("hovered");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".button-one").tooltip({
        position: "center right",
        delay:300,
        effect: 'slide',
        direction:'right',
        offset: [30, -12],
        slideOffset: 30,
        slideFade:'true',
        slideInSpeed:350,
        slideOutSpeed:250,
        onShow: hovering,
        onHide: hovering
    });

    $(".button-two").tooltip({ 
        position: "bottom left",
        delay:300,
        effect: 'slide',
        direction:'left',
        offset: [-34, 20],
        slideOffset: 30,
        slideFade:'true',
        slideInSpeed:350,
        slideOutSpeed:250,
        onShow: hovering,
        onHide: hovering
    });
...
```

At last change your CSS code, where the styles for #button are located into this:

```
.button {
    background:transparent url(../images/red-circle.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -2px;
    display:block;
    height:23px;
    width:23px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-999em;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}

/**
 * mouseover state, 
 * elements with the "hovered" class now behave
 * like ones in mouseover state
 */
.button:hover, .button.hovered{
    background-position:0 -25px;    
    opacity: 1;
}

/* clicked state */
.button:focus {
    background-position:0 -25px;
}
```

---

To have the tooltip getting closed when a link is clicked, put this code after your tooltip definitions:

```
$(".tooltip, .tooltip-brite, ... all your tooltip-classes").live("click", function() {  
    $(this).prev().tooltip().hide();
});

$(".button-two, .button-one, ... all your button-classes").live("click", function() {   
    $(this).tooltip().hide();
});
```

This will close the tooltip when ether the div with the red dot indside or the tooltip box is clicked.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing something wrong, but I tried your suggested code, and it just shows the tooltip, nothing new happens. I'm trying to find a way to tie the red dots filling in to the tooltips, so that each one does not turn off while hovering over its related tooltip.

Comment: below is the css code of the circle sprite for each button - i'm trying to somehow tie these to each of the tooltips. For example, if the mouse moves over red circle button 11 and then onto the tooltip for button 11, I do not want the red circle hover state to turn off until it leaves the tooltip.
 
`#button {
 background:transparent url(../images/red-circle.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -2px;
 display:block;
 height:23px;
 width:23px;
}

#button:hover {
 background-position:0 -25px; 
 opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: thanks for walking me through that, it works perfect! Thanks makes sense now.

One more thing, what is the best way to make sure the tooltip is closed when any link is clicked inside of it? For some reason on mobile devices (iPad), when you finger hits to open the hover state and then you hit a link on it to go to another page, and then hit the back button back to the map, the last tooltip stays stuck open.